# Should basic questions be entertained with the idea of using them as signposts?

Tags: discussion

So, I answered this question:

[Are Christians monotheists and what is the nature of Jesus? (i.e. Give me the basics of Christianity please)](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/22767/are-christians-monotheists-and-what-is-the-nature-of-jesus-i-e-give-me-the-ba)

It's <strike>not a great question</strike> really too basic for this site.  In answering it, there wasn't much new or useful content generated - but it did end up being useful in my mind as an entry point for the uninitiated.  I think there's value in that - but it's not necessarily expert level.

That said, there are situations where I think a "table of contents" is useful.

So, should I have done that or not?

Answer (score 4):

My thoughts on this:

1. The question contained many sub-questions which is undesirable.
2. I don't think any questions here are too basic. The fact that *"[anybody can ask a question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help)"* implies we are bound to get basic questions. As long as they are not duplicates (and I think this question is guilty of that), I think it is fine to answer them. At the least, it steers Google traffic this way. And at its best, it helps us learn to explain sometimes complicated Christian topics in ways that can be easily understood by a layman.

Conclusion: I think this question would be better off split into multiple questions that could otherwise be closed (as duplicates or off-topic) and others that can (and should be) answered.

BTW, I didn't downvote or vote to close because I wanted to keep your answer there. Personally, I'm glad you (and [Mawia](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/22775/62)) answered it. Who knows what good you did on this or on the other side of eternity?

Answer (score 2):

My concern here is that we do not know, about the author. We may have someone who is just becoming interested Christianity and I fear that we could kill that curiousity before it has a chance to have that person accept Christ.
Specifically I know that using the internet is much more popular with kids than with adults, and the more sophomiric the question the higher the chance that the person asking the question is young.
I do not think it is a good practice to be condesending to any question or questioner.

Comment: Civility at all times should be taken as a given